# How to transform abstract finite group to permutation group?

Tags: permutation, group-theory

It seems that *Mathematica* **only** has group functionality for permutation groups? Then there is a step to transform the abstract finite one to a permutation one.

As an example, consider the following problem

> Suppose $G=\langle a,b|a^2=1,b^3=1,(ab)^2=1\rangle$, try to compute $ab^2ab^2a$.

It can proceed by viewing the elements of group just as a string, and the rule of group can be view as a rule of string replace. Any way, I would like to use `NonCommutativeMultiply` instead:

Firstly, let us define the rule, basically, we only need to define the rule for $ab$ and $ba$, since whenever we know how to commute these two generators, then we can use the fact $a^2=1=b^3$ to simplify our expression. It is not hard to compute $ab=b^2a$, $ba=ab^2$:

```
rel = {c___ ** a ** a ** d___ :> c ** i ** d, 
  c___ ** b ** b ** b ** d___ :> c ** i ** d, 
  c___ ** a ** b ** d___ :> c ** b ** b ** a ** d, 
  c___ ** b ** a ** d___ :> c ** a ** b ** b ** d , a___ ** i :> a, 
  i ** a___ :> a}
```

Now, let us define the set of group elements. Since $a$ is a order 2 element and $b$ is order $3$, we know that $G$ must be a subgroup of order $6=o(a)\times o(b)$, thus the elements can be expressed by

```
set = {i, a, b, b ** b, a ** b, b ** a}
```

Lastly, we can compute what's the results of $a$ multiply from left:

```
a ** # & /@ set/.rel
```

The problem: It seems my rule has not do the function of simplify the expression, as you can see the results is

```
{a, NonCommutativeMultiply[i], b ** b ** a, b ** b ** a ** b, i ** b, 
   b ** b ** a ** a}
```

the element `b**b**a**a` should be `b**b`, so please help me to correct the rule?

The correct result should be

```
aset = {a, i, a ** b, b ** a, b, b ** b}
```

form which we can find the permutation by

```
FindPermutation[set, aset]
```

which gives

```
Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For simplicity, let's set

```
ncm[a__] := NonCommutativeMultiply[a]
```

My recommendation for this problem is to choose a "normal order" for the group elements. That is, I would choose to represent the group elements in such a way that all the `a`'s are to the left of the `b`'s. To do this, we define our set of replacements in such a way that `b`'s always move to the right:

```
rel = {ncm[c___, a, a, d___] :> ncm[c, i, d]
  , ncm[c___, b, b, b, d___] :> ncm[c,i, d]
  , ncm[c___, b, b, a, d___] :> ncm[c, a, b, d]
  , ncm[c___, b, a, d___] :> ncm[c, a, b, b, d]
  , ncm[a__, i] :> ncm[a]
  , ncm[i, a__] :> ncm[a]
  , ncm[a_] :> a
 }
```

This guarantees that when we apply the rules repeatedly (which we have to do), the process will eventually terminate.

Then, we get the group elements into normal order by using `ReplaceRepeated` with the replacement rules `rel`:

```
set = {i, a, b, b ** b, a ** b, b ** a} //. rel
(* {i, a, b, b ** b, a ** b, a ** b ** b} *)
```

So, instead of using `b ** a` as one of the elements, we use the slightly more complicated (but it turns out easier to use) `a ** b ** b`.

Finally, then, multiplication on the left by `a` results in

```
aset = a ** # & /@ set //. rel
(* {a, i, a ** b, a ** b ** b, b, b ** b} *)
```

and

```
FindPermutation[set, aset]
(* Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}] *)
```

---

#### Brief explanation

To answer your questions:

- `NonCommutativeMultiply` has very little rules associated with it. In particular, `ncm[a]` doesn't evaluate, i.e. it just evaluates to `ncm[a]`. So we have to add the rule that if we have `ncm[i]`, for instance, this will evaluate to `i`.
- `_` is `Blank`. It is a pattern that will match *any* single expression. `__` is `BlankSequence`. It is a pattern will match *any* *sequence* of one or more expressions. `___` is `BlankNullSequence`. It will match *any* sequence of expressions, including the `Null` Sequence. Meditate on the results of these three evaluations:

  `{f[], f[a], f[a, b]} /. f[_] :> f[1]`

  `{f[], f[a], f[a, b]} /. f[__] :> f[1]`

  `{f[], f[a], f[a, b]} /. f[___] :> f[1]`

Comment: Nice answer, +1

Comment: thanks a lot, the idea to move b to right is great!! Could you please explain why we need `ncm[a_]:>a` to stop the loop of replacement? And what's the difference of `a_`, `a__`, and `a___` in this answer? I have read the manual, but still confused when I try to use it, if possible, please explain it to me the difference, Thanks again!

Comment: by the way, the second rule should be replaced to be `ncm[c,i,d]`, or it may produce `ncm[]`.

Comment: @vanabel: Yes absolutely, thanks for pointing that out! I'll fix it now.