# Filter pattern from a list

Tags: replacement, filtering, group-theory

I have group elements, that I'd like to condense down according to group rules. Take the modular group. This has generators $S,T$ that satisfy the groups relations $S^2 = I, (ST)^3 = I$.

So given a group element as a list of generators (for instance, $S T^2 S$ I'd write as {S,T,T,S} in Mathematica), I'd like to collapse the expression down according to group rules.

For instance, in our example, we'd have

```
Collapse[{S,T,S,S,T}] = {S,T,T}
```

I've tried using ReplaceAll, but can't get it to match substrings. StringReplace seems to have the correct functionality, but only works on actual strings.

How would one go about doing this?

Comment: In general, this is sort of a hard problem. My take on it in the past has been to choose a "normal order", since writing group elements in terms of generators is not unique in general. Maybe start with [this question and answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96111/how-to-transform-abstract-finite-group-to-permutation-group/96113#96113). I know there are many more on this site. The real question is, what do you want to do with this? Do you want to have a list of all the group elements in terms of the generators? How do you decide when you're done?

Comment: By the way, does this particular presentation lead to a finite group?

Answer (score 4):

Using replacement [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)s

```
collapse[lst_?VectorQ] := lst //. {
   {b___, S, S, e___} :> {b, e},
   {b___, S, T, S, T, S, T, e___} :> {b, e}}

collapse[{S, T, S, S, T}]

(*  {S, T, T}  *)

collapse[{S, S, T, S, T, S, T, S, T, S, S, T}]

(*  {T, T}  *)
```

Comment: I think I would go with `{b___, T, S, T, S, T, e___} :> {b, S, e}` instead of the second one. It along with the first rule makes your second rule, but this one will get more cases. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Using `SubstitutionSystem`:**

```
collapse[lst_?VectorQ, rule_] := Module[{
    str = StringJoin @@ ToString /@ lst},
   Characters@SubstitutionSystem[rule, str]
   ];

vecs = {{S, T, S, S, T}, {S, S, T, S, T, S, T, S, T, S, S, T}};

rule = {"SS" -> "", "STSTST" -> ""}
```

---

*Usage:*

```
collapse[#, rule] & /@ vecs
```

---

*Result:*

> {{"S", "T", "T"}, {"T", "T"}}

---

Here I have assumed that the input vector has `Symbol`s, so a conversion to `String` is necessary. If the input vectors already have `String` characters, then another function with the same name but a different input can be defined. To get symbols back, one can additionally run `ToExpression` on the output of the function.